# Why do these programs (that differ only in one printf statement) have such different output?

Tags: c, string

**Program #1:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *getString()
{
   char str[] = "GfG";
   printf("%s \n", str); 
   return str;
}    
int main()
{
    printf("%s", getString()); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
GfG
GfG
```

**Program #2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *getString()
{
    char str[] = "GfG";
    return str;
}    
int main()
{
    printf("%s", getString()); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> (garbage value)

Please explain why because of only a `printf` statement output differs. What is exact description?

Comment: What about `char *str = "GfG";`?  That would have been an interesting addition to your question.  Especially if you make them `const char *`.

Answer (score 10):

Because both programs show undefined behavior.

When the `getString` function returns the `str` array object is destroyed and trying to access it after its lifetime is undefined behavior.

You can fix your program using a string literal, as string literals have static storage duration and their lifetime is the entire duration of the program:

```
char *getString(void)
{
    char *str = "GfG";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `const char *` for both `return` and `str` to be sure.  Possibly some compiler might not enforce the "don't allow constant strings to be written" rule.

Answer (score 3):

```
char str[] = "GfG";
```

declares an automatic variable.  It is only valid to access this inside the scope it was declared in (the function `getString`).  Attempting to use it anywhere else results in undefined behaviour.  You've been unlucky that the first version appeared to work.

When `getString` returns, the stack region used to store `str` may be reused.  If this happens, `printf` will end up reading further through memory until it finds either a `'\0'` byte or crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You must either allocate the memory with `malloc` or try with `static`.

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: There is no need repeat the same thing as other have already. My answers tell how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that arrays are not passed by value in C, they are passed by address. Since `str` is defined in `getstring()`, after the control returns to `main()` it is not valid to access that specific address.If you do happen to access the address, the result will be unpredictable. Just remember that the C compiler does not check for incorrect memory access requests in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable `char str[] = "GfG";` scope is limited to the function. So when you try to print that in function scope, it works. But when you try to access that from outside of that function its `undefined behavior.`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *getString()
{
    char str[] = "GfG"; // Local variable, so once you try to return that it is undefined
    return str;
}    
int main()
{
    printf("%s", getString()); 
    return 0;
}
```

Go through the below link you will get some more example.
[Does local variable be deleted from memory when this function is called in main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015002/does-local-variable-be-deleted-from-memory-when-this-function-is-called-in-main)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `char str[] = "GfG";` is put on the stack inside the first function. It returns a pointer to that. The caller tries to use it and give it to `printf()`, but in the mean time, the "old" stack content was already overwritten.

There may be a difference between them which makes the first one keep the old content a bit longer, but there is no guarantee for that and therefore it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I just tried it, and it seems that in the 2nd version the string is silently optimized away: it is not used inside the function, and returning it is UB anyway. So it just gets dropped.